# Unable to load the downloaded model from s3 into databricks using .from_pretrained and passing the s3_path for loading the model

Tags: python, amazon-s3, nlp, large-language-model, llama

The model i am trying to load is llama-13b-hf which i have downloaded from the hugging face

Below is the code i am using

```
from torch import cuda, bfloat16
import transformers
```

```
model_id = 'meta-llama/Llama-2-13b-hf'
```

```
device = f'cuda:{cuda.current_device()}' if cuda.is_available() else 'cpu's3_path = "s3://some_bucket/dev/datascience/LLM"
```

### set quantization configuration to load large model with less GPU memory

### this requires the `bitsandbytes` library

```
bnb_config =               transformers.BitsAndBytesConfig(load_in_4bit=True,bnb_4bit_quant_type='nf4',bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=True,bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=bfloat16)
```

### begin initializing HF items, need auth token for these

```
hf_auth = ''
model_config = transformers.AutoConfig.from_pretrained(s3_path,use_auth_token=hf_auth)
```

```
model = transformers.AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_id,local_files_only=True,trust_remote_code=True,config=model_config,quantization_config=bnb_config,device_map=device,use_auth_token=hf_auth)model.eval()print(f"Model loaded on {device}")
```

Also i have added the image of the s3_bucket and it's content

OSError: Can't load the configuration of 's3://some_bucket/dev/datascience/LLM'. If you were trying to load it from 'https://huggingface.co/models', make sure you don't have a local directory with the same name. Otherwise, make sure 's3://some_bucket/dev/datascience/LLM' is the correct path to a directory containing a config.json file